# Mongodb findAndModify - Read uncommitted?

Tags: mongodb

i have  a question about the atomicity of mongodb FindAndModify() in a standalone db.
I have a "counter" document like this:

```
{ 
_id:ObjectId(""),
 label: counter,
 value: 1
}
```

And i have to inc and read this counter in a multi thread enviroment.

My question is about the read phase of the FindAndModify.
From Mongdb documention i understand that between the find and the update no operation can occur but i also read that in mongodb is allowed the uncommitted read (default isolation).

So considering that is possibile to have this situation:

```
thread1: time1 -> find document with value= 1 (read uncommit op -> permitted);
thread2: time2 -> find docoument with value= 1 (read uncommit op -> permitted);
reader1: t3 -> inc value (write op);
reader2: t4 -> inc value (write op).
```

And the query is without "new" option so the old document (before the update) will be returned to every thread.

So does the old document returned to each thread will be the same and it will have the value field = 1?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe this isn't explicitly answered in the documentation, which you should link to.

Comment: Yes it isn't answered in mongodb documentation. That's why i ask in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I check different topics, articles and directly the source code of FindAndModify at this link:
[https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/commands/find_and_modify.cpp](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/command/findAndModify.html#gsc.tab=0)

The findAndModify is atomic also with the flag new:false because to run it takes directly a write lock on the entire collection (global).

[Another example is here](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/command/findAndModify.html#gsc.tab=0)